# Default build settings Eclipse CDT

Tags: mingw, eclipse-cdt

Is there any way to change build settings which are used when I create new project in Eclipse CDT? Some of toolchain setting I have to change every time I creating new project.

Comment: Agree, this is a general PITA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is now way to do this in a nice way. A not so nice way would be to create an empty project with all the needed settings and to make a copy of this whenever a new project is needed.

Answer (score 1):

The build settings are stored in the .cproject file and the .settings directory at the top of the project.  You can copy and paste them from one project to another then change all the project name wherever it shows up in the .cproject file.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question just now when I asked google the same thing :)
The way to do it:

Window --> Preferences --> C/C++ (For example) --> New CDT Project Wizard --> select the desired toolchain and make it preferred or not preferred.

Hope this is still relevant.

Comment: This allows changing the default toolchain when a new project is created, but it seems that there is no way to configure the default settings of a particular toolchain. It seems the only way to change those settings is to do it one by one after a project is created.